# can I use a variable within getElementsByClassName

Tags: javascript, variables, getelementsbyclassname

I'am wondering if it is possible to create a string and use it as a variable within getElementsByClassName to get the Id of the div?

```
<div id="000" class="item 1 currColor">
<div id="001" class="item 2 currColor">

var class_name = "1" + "currColor";
var get_color = document.getElementsByClassName(class_Name)[0].id;
```

Comment: Sure. Why not try it out? Does it not work?

Comment: Have you tried this? It would seem possible to me.

Comment: `var class_name = "1" + "currColor";` Careful — you should have a space in between "1" and "currColor".

Comment: TypeError: document.getElementsByClassName(color_class)[0] is    undefined
[Break On This Error]  

var get_color = document.getElementsByClassName(color_class)[0].id

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can: http://jsfiddle.net/6XZRf/

But javascript is case sensitive, so `class_name` is not the same as `class_Name`.

Moreover, `"1" + "currColor"` is `"1currColor"`. You haven't any elements with class `"1currColor"`, you have to change

```
<div id="000" class="item 1 currColor">
<div id="001" class="item 2 currColor">
```

into

```
<div id="000" class="item 1currColor">
<div id="001" class="item 2currColor">
```

or the reverse, change

```
var class_name = "1currColor";
```

into

```
var class_name = "1 currColor";
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason your code doesn't work is that you're searching for an element with class `1currColor` but you really mean to look for elements with both classes.

You can do it using `document.getElementsByClassName("1"+ " " + "currColor")` Notice the space in between the two classes. That means find me objects that contain both classes

Answer (score 0):

Of course, But you are missing the space between the class names,

`var class_name = "1" + "currColor";` should be `var class_name = "1" + " currColor";`

But this will make more sense on usage of classes,

```
//note the class name
var class_name = "item" + " currColor";
var get_color = document.getElementsByClassName(class_Name)[0].id;
```

Here is a [simple demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WmYkH/2/)